# How to map the F11 and F12 keys to Volume Up/Volume Down

Tags: keyboard

I have chosen to use the F1-F12 keys with their original -PC- behavior, because I want F5 to refresh the page in Firefox! (and not control the backlight of the keyboard)

Now I would like to "remap" the Volume Up/Volume Down key as originaly intended: F11 and F12 keys (I'm used to that). I don't want to have to press Fn everytime.

I've searched everywhere I can't find a way to do that (for now I have to press Fn+F11 and Fn+F12).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/), you can individually remap the function keys.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I've installed it but I didn't find the option to remap a *specific* function key (only possible to remap all FX keys). I'm not home right now, I'll check later.

Comment: @Matthieu Brain fart - it's FunctionFlip (see answer edit). I don't have it on my home computer, only my work Mac, so I misremembered the name.

Comment: Excellent! This is *exactly* what I'm looking for. I hope I wont have conflicts with KeyRemap4Macbook, but i won't be using it for functions keys so it should be ok.