# Quick text string search, perhaps in Applescript, for fixed search term so can be bound to keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, search, text

I spend a lot of time editing text. At work, I use the medical software Epic where the key <kbd>F3</kbd> is bound to search and select the next instance of “foo bar” from the cursor. If <kbd>F3</kbd>  is pressed again, the next instance of “foo bar” is selected and so on until it returns to the start of the document. This makes editing template documents quick.

**Is there a way to create a custom search function (maybe with AppleScript) that searches for a predefined term that I can assign to a specific key?**

Is there a way that I can replicate this behaviour (or with a different keyboard shortcut), ideally across Apps, on Mac OS (10.13.6)?

Comment: That’s actually not an Epic convention, but a Windows one.  In other words, all Windows computers use F3 as search.  What you want to do, is remap “Search” to F3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to map the F11 and F12 keys to Volume Up/Volume Down](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26934/how-to-map-the-f11-and-f12-keys-to-volume-up-volume-down)

Comment: Also, this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/286910/can-i-remap-commandf-in-safari. This is for Safari specifically, but you can make it global

Comment: Thank you Allan for the suggestions – it shows how long since I used a Windows computer regulary! I may not have been clear, but instead of triggering the search box, I would like to instantly search for a pre-defined search term i.e. jump to the next instance of that text and be able to do this repeatedly, just one button press. I don't think I can do that with the FunctionFlip software that your suggested answer links to, but any other suggestion welcome.

Comment: Where does the XXX come from which F3 searches for?

Comment: Ahhh... let me retract the close vote.  What you want to do is have a custom search assigned to a kepress.  This is done with AppleScript.  We have some **awesome** Applescript folks here so lets give them a chance to see the question

Comment: @nohillside -- the XXX could be any pre-defined text string. In fact, I am accustomed to use three asterisks but essentially any placeholder text. The intention would be to keep the pre-defined text string the same but to build document templates to contain this search string in the appropriate places.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question then: Is the XXX something which can be defined upfront (e.g. when writing the AppleScript Allan mentioned) or is this a text to be taken from a document etc. at the moment F3 is pressed?

Comment: @nohillside: sorry if I missed your point -- the text would be defined upfront e.g. in Applescript.